# Zxing cant find my barcode in image

Tags: java, zxing

Well, i have a paper with some information and 3 barcode. The user will scan (with a scan device) this paper and submit in our software.

Our software should recognized this image and extract the barcodes from it. I'm using ZXING library but i just got "NotFoundException" because any readable barcode is found.

This is my image:
[image]

This is my code:

```
LuminanceSource source = new BufferedImageLuminanceSource(bufferedImage);  
        BinaryBitmap bitmap = new BinaryBitmap(new HybridBinarizer(source));  
        Reader reader = new MultiFormatReader();  
        Result result = reader.decode(bitmap);  
         logger.debug(result.getText());
```

How can i solve this problem ? I can't say to customer crop the paper before scan.

**EDIT 1:**

I tried crop the image and didn't work too.
My image croped:
[image]

**EDIT 2:**
I'm using Code39 format in barcode, so i tried use Code39Reader class from ZXing but i got the some problem

Comment: If the position of your bar code is *reasonably* the same from one document to the next (in this one I count two bar codes!) you can make ZXING's work easier by having your program crop the image before attempting to scan it.

Comment: Two of them are the same, aren't they? Anyway, if you can't get it to work with a cropped image, the problem lies elsewhere. Is this a barcode format that ZXing is supposed to understand?

Comment: I'm using barcode Code39, i don't know if ZXing understand this format.